# NodeJS Json sort by child array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, sorting

I want to sort my object by it´s child array.

```
let partners = [
  {
    Name: "A",
    Sectors: [
      { Code: "AA1", Total: 10 },
      { Code: "AA2", Total: 70 }
    ]
  },
  {
    Name: "B",
    Sectors: [
      { Code: "AA1", Total: 20 },
      { Code: "AA2", Total: 60 }
    ]
  },
  {
    Name: "C",
    Sectors: [
      { Code: "AA1", Total: 40 },
      { Code: "AA2", Total: 50 }
    ]
  }
];
```

Lets say I want to sort by the prop Sectors where `Code = AA1 DESC`. The result (prop Name) would be:

C, B, A

Or if I need `Code = AA2 DESC`, would be A, B, C

I had some dificults with a simple sort like this:

```
let sorted = partners.sort((a, b) => a.Sectors.Total - b.Sectors.Total);

sorted.forEach((sortedData) => console.log(sortedData));
```

[Here is a SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-e9r6w?file=/index.js:0-486)

Here is the correct answer with a change to acept empty.

```js
let partners = [
{"Name":"E","Sectors": null}, 
{"Name":"A","Sectors":[{"Code":"AA1","Total":10},{"Code":"AA2","Total":70}]},
{"Name":"B","Sectors":[{"Code":"AA1","Total":20},{"Code":"AA2","Total":60}]},
{"Name":"C","Sectors":[{"Code":"AA1","Total":40},{"Code":"AA2","Total":50}]}, 
{"Name":"D","Sectors": null},
{"Name":"P","Sectors": []}
]

partners.sort((a, b) => {
    const get = (arr, key, val) => {
    return arr.find(o => o[key] === val) || {};
  }
  
  let sA = {}, sB = {}
  
  try {
    sA = get(a.Sectors, 'Code', 'AA1')
    sB = get(b.Sectors, 'Code', 'AA1')
  } catch (e) {}
  
  
  return !!sB.Total - !!sA.Total || sB.Total - sA.Total 
})

console.log(partners)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to this with `sort` and `find` methods. Inside the sort you need to find element from the Sectors array with specific `Code` and then compare the `Total` values.

```js
let partners = [{"Name":"A","Sectors":[{"Code":"AA1","Total":10},{"Code":"AA2","Total":70}]},{"Name":"B","Sectors":[{"Code":"AA1","Total":20},{"Code":"AA2","Total":60}]},{"Name":"C","Sectors":[{"Code":"AA1","Total":40},{"Code":"AA2","Total":50}]}]

partners.sort((a, b) => {
  const sA = a.Sectors.find(({ Code }) => Code === 'AA1');
  const sB = b.Sectors.find(({ Code }) => Code === 'AA1');
  return sB.Total - sA.Total
})

console.log(partners)
```

Comment: sometimes a.Sectors or b.Sector will be null or empty... empty is not a problema, how can I do some kind of nullish to may this sort not break?

Comment: I am running this on NodeJS 12, so I dont have the question mark (?) to put like const sA = a?.Sectors?.find(({ Code }) => Code === 'AA1');

Comment: You could do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/5bjuoLem/ . `!!sB.Total - !!sA.Total` this will put null values last and `sB.Total - sA.Total` here you can modify order of sB and sA to get asc or desc order.

Comment: does not work with empty´s... on the lista there are Sectors null or Empty...

Comment: Just changet to return arr.find(o => o[key] === val) || {}; and worked fine... but null comes in front of empty... that wird... thanks!

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR Then maybe something like this https://jsfiddle.net/gwqspzx4/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could take a dynamic approach and find the wanted value for sorting.

```js
const
    sortBy = (fn, order) => (a, b) => (order === 'ASC' || -1) * (fn(a) - fn(b)),
    getValue = code => o => o.Sectors.find(({ Code }) => Code === code)?.Total || 0,
    partners = [{ Name: "A", Sectors: [{ Code: "AA1", Total: 10 }, { Code: "AA2", Total: 70 }] }, { Name: "B", Sectors: [{ Code: "AA1", Total: 20 }, { Code: "AA2", Total: 60 }] }, { Name: "C", Sectors: [{ Code: "AA1", Total: 40 }, { Code: "AA2", Total: 50 }] }];

console.log(partners.sort(sortBy(getValue('AA1'), 'DESC')));
console.log(partners.sort(sortBy(getValue('AA2'), 'DESC')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```